# showing up of published android app (update) take different time on different handsets?

Tags: android, updates, publish

After uploading app update on play store, I have found that on some devices this uploaded (new version) app is visible on (PC) app store website within half and hour. But on mobile devices it is not so. On some devices it is visible after 2 hours and on some it takes 5 to 10 hours and sometimes even a day or two. Even if we open play store and find the app online, only 'installed' button will be shown, not the 'update' button. WHY?

I asked this question in google play developers support forum and I got following answer:

*Hi Masoom, we are unable to assist you because this Google Play Help Forum focuses on user-level issues with the Google Play digital content store and related Google apps, not Android development or publishing issues. I recommend that you check the list of Developer Support Resources.*

Can anybody clarify.

Comment: what is there in this to give a negative mark?

Comment: Please see [this Meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic) for a discussion of what is and is not on-topic about the Play Store and other app distribution channels.

Comment: I got it. OK and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The type of handset doesn't have an effect on whether the update is displayed, the only factor is whether the app is already installed on a device or not. If it is installed on a device then the update will take longer to show but if the handset doesn't have the app installed it will be displayed faster.

I quote "App updates take some time to be delivered to existing users. If you’ve submitted an update that hasn’t appeared on Google Play, please wait at least 24 hours before contacting our support team."

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en-GB

Comment: the question is = why?

Comment: Don't know but I guess it's because If an app is already installed your device doesn't constantly look for updates and only looks for update every x amount of hours.

Comment: but we manually open playstore and browse it for apps. isn't it?

Comment: Never ask for votes. Your question is off-topic on stackoverflow. See 2 comment under question. Just be glad people still try to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Play service caches a lot of data and refreshes them in a given interval. In most cases a user will see the update if he resets his device cache.

Additionally, if you mean the notification telling the user that an update is available: The interval checking for this is longer. Also Google Play tends to wait for more than one update in order to group them (i guess to not annoy users).

Comment: no i don't mean the notification but while manually checking / searching for the app / app update.